# Android: google+ login doesn't work in released signed apk

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

google+ login code works perfectly for my app in debug mode. but for released apk it doesn't. it goes in onConnectionFailed method. I have SHA1 fingerprint for realease version, but don't know where to put it...

Comment: put that sha1 key insted of old sha1

Comment: will it work in debug mode?

Comment: yes if you debug using same pc

Comment: so, basically, i will have to change it, every time i work on another computer?

Comment: yes see my ans here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35634393/4146722

Comment: thanks, man, i would thumb u up, but its not in answers :D

Comment: i tried it and now it works in release apk, but not in debug mode. is there any way that it works in both ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use release version of SHA1 fingerprint instead of old SHA1.